# IAM & Admin menu option missing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, admin

I am new to GCP so please excuse my ignorance here. While reading about IAM, I noticed that I don't have the menu option for "IAM and Admin". The organization and project was newly set up. In addition, I also set myself up as super-admin, organization admin and owner. Is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  The option has now been split out into "Admin" option which covers areas such as privacy & security, organization Policies, Manage Resources, Settings and others...Other areas that are more IAM-related such as IAM, Identity & organization, Service accounts, and such...are now separated out and into a new home under "identity & Security".

I had to watch a few identity-related YouTube videos to find out the previous menu selections...just to figure this one out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Identity and Access Management (IAM) lets you create and manage permissions for Google Cloud resources.

And you can access to “Identity & Security” menu though this link:

[Identity and Access Management (IAM)](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/?_ga=2.170930213.423459696.1609163522-549298192.1605204650&_gac=1.156815177.1607379213.CjwKCAiAwrf-BRA9EiwAUWwKXs96xT84WhL0QBiVkLmROl1-j7OMiZgF9_fG3wrg7DyO4b74YpHFjRoCjlcQAvD_BwE)

Additionally you can consult the  official documentation in the following link:

[Identity and Access Management documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs)